# Mapping not applied into subclasses

Tags: java, mapstruct

I have the following mapping:

```
@Mapper
public interface ParticulierMapper {

ParticulierMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper( ParticulierMapper.class );
TParticulier toDTO(Particulier particulier);
Particulier toEntity(TParticulier particulier);
TParticulierAttributMeta toDTO(ParticulierAttributMeta particulierAttributMeta);
ParticulierAttributMeta toEntity(TParticulierAttributMeta particulierAttributMeta);
TAdresse toDTO(Adresse adresse);
Adresse toEntity(TAdresse adresse);

default String toEntity(TGufidValue value){
    return value.getGufid();
}
default TGufidValue toDTO(String value){
    TGufidValue tGufidValue=new TGufidValue();
    tGufidValue.setGufid(value);
    return tGufidValue;
}
default LocalDateTime map(XMLGregorianCalendar value){
    return value.toGregorianCalendar().toZonedDateTime().toLocalDateTime();
}
}`
```

The TGufidValue is correctly convert into TParticulier/Particulier but is skipped into the Adresse/TAdresse conversion as shown:

```
public Adresse toEntity(TAdresse adresse) {

    if ( adresse == null ) {

        return null;
    }

    Adresse adresse1 = new Adresse();

    adresse1.setLibelleAdresse( adresse.getLibelleAdresse() );

    adresse1.setParticulierAttributMetas( tParticulierAttributMetaListToParticulierAttributMetaList( adresse.getParticulierAttributMetas() ) );

    adresse1.setBoite( adresse.getBoite() );

    adresse1.setComplement( adresse.getComplement() );

    adresse1.setLocalisationSpatiale( adresse.getLocalisationSpatiale() );

    adresse1.setLocalite( adresse.getLocalite() );

    adresse1.setNumero( adresse.getNumero() );

    adresse1.setRegion( adresse.getRegion() );

    adresse1.setVille( adresse.getVille() );

    adresse1.setVoie( adresse.getVoie() );

    return adresse1;
}
```

All the field of TAddress that are TGufidValue object are skipped and so doesn't appears in the TAdresse conversion.
Is there something special to do to make this conversion globally available on other class than TParticulier/Particulier ?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind I found my problem. just that dto and entity field didn't had the same name when was using TGufidValue. A warning could be interesting while compiling to indicate that there are some unmatch fields.

Comment: If a property in the target bean, in your case `Adresse` has not been mapped you should get a warning. You can even fail the build, i.e. report an error. Have a look at the [`Mapper#unmappedTargetPolicy](http://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/api/org/mapstruct/Mapper.html#unmappedTargetPolicy--). If there really was no warning please open an issue